# Showing error without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm making a comment feature for my website and need to make it so that after the person submits a comment (and it contains errors), it will show the error without refreshing the page. I know almost nothing of AJAX/JQuery, so I'll need some help.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['reply_submit'])) {
    $reply = $_POST['new_reply'];
    $reply_message = "";

    if(empty($reply)) {
      $reply_message = "Your comment is too short.";
    }
  }
?>

<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form class="no-margin" method="POST" action="">
      <textarea name="new_reply" placeholder="Write a reply..."></textarea>
      <button name="reply_submit" class="btn post-button" type="submit">Post' . (isset($reply_message) ? '<div class="comment-warning">' . $reply_message . '</div>' : '') . '</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I need it to do is, if the person's comment box doesn't meet the criteria (in this case, an empty field), I need it to show this error line without refreshing the page:

```
<button name="reply_submit" class="btn post-button" type="submit">Post' . (isset($reply_message) ? '<div class="comment-warning">' . $reply_message . '</div>' : '') . '</button>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to do the validation at the client side via Javascript. Instead of simply using a button of type `submit`, write a function and bind it to the button's `onclick()` event.

Something like this:

```
function submit() {
  if (document.getElementById("myTextarea").value=='') {
    alert("Your comment is too short.");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript

HTML:

```
<button name="reply_submit" class="btn post-button" onclick="validate()">Post comment</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function validate(){
  reply = document.getElementById('new_reply').value;
  if (reply==null || reply=="")
    {
    alert("Your comment is too short.");
    return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For basic validations like empty fields or length of input box you can use jQuery validate plugin -- http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ or write something of your own.

You can use jQuery for a better AJAX/error handling. Check the documentation for jQuery AJAX here -- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html", //URL to send the request
  success: function() {
    //do something. This is fired when your response is successful
  },
  error: function() {
    //highlight the field that has error or do something else here.
  }
);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm confused as to what the url part of the code does. Could you explain it further?